# Cost value of a specific spot in cost map inflation layer?

Tags: ros, navigation, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a tool to see the cost value at a specified place in the cost map? Using the 2d cost layer map with inflation layer. With lethal value set at the default 100 I can not navigate threw an area I should be able to. When I put it to something really high I can navigate but picking some arbitrary large number doesn’t feel like a great idea.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407617/cost-value-of-a-specific-spot-in-cost-map-inflation-layer?/) by [johnjamesmiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/1652/johnjamesmiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2022-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are visualized via the color scheme in rviz, but obviously that's not an exact value. You should subscribe to the costmap topic and query it for the location value you're interested in.

The `lethal_cost_threshold` parameter is only used by the static layer for interpreting the probabilistic values in the map you provide it for the static layer only. https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/6d58247e3c3273753a7cfde04ace8b43fab1231e/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/static_layer.cpp#L260-L275

That should not be impacting your sensor processing or other layers / costmap in general. If you set it higher than that, it thresholds it back down to 100 (https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/6d58247e3c3273753a7cfde04ace8b43fab1231e/nav2_costmap_2d/plugins/static_layer.cpp#L162) so I don't think there is actually any difference between setting it to 101 (or 700) vs 100.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1